# Time sync in VM between Windows as host and CentOS as guest without network

Tags: linux, virtualbox, clock

A question concerning the time synchronization between the host and the guest System.

I am using Windows 7 as my host OS and CentOS 7 is installed as VM in an Oracle VirtualBox environment without network access.

I am searching for a solution which allows the VM to get the correct time after a reboot or a snapshot. The challenge is, that I would collect the time from the host system without installation of additional tools. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you guest is `Centos Linux` then you need to install DKMS (Dynamic Kernel Module Support) package.

```
# yum install dkms
# yum install virtualbox-guest-additions
```

For reference you can [check this](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changetimesync)

Without `virtualbox-guest-additions` tool

Disable the `ntp` service

`chkconfig ntpd off`

**For Windows Host**

Go to
C:\Documents and Settings\.VirtualBox\Machines\
and edit the xml file.
–>Create a backup of this file<–

Add the line

`VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled "0"`

Comment: **"Without installation of additional tools"**, do you mean that your `yum install` doesn't install anything?

Comment: hi, no yum is working no problem. i installed many thinks and all is working. i only recognized that the time is not synchronizing when I am working without network. So the idea was to sync the guest VM(CentOS7 ) with the host (Win7). But at the moment I have no success.
and this command is not working for me: # yum install virtualbox-guest-additions

Comment: Check the recent edit. hope it works for you.

Comment: unforutnately not..  hm..

Comment: Does that line exist on that location.

Comment: i solved it with the installation of the guest additions. mounted the iso file and instaled it. now i have the right time. thanks